# Showing $(\log n)^k = O(n)$, where $k\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: asymptotics

I'm somewhat convinced by taking the limits of $\frac{n}{(\log{n})^k}$ (i.e. proving little $o$ to prove big $O$), but am struggling to prove that it is the case via the formal definition; say the following:

We say that a function $f(n)$ is $O(g(n))$ if there exists a positive real number
$M$ and a real number
$x_0$ such that
$$|f(x)|\leq M\cdot g(x)\quad {\text{ for all }x\geq x_{0}.}$$

I think it boils down to showing $(\log{n})^k \geq M\cdot n$, but I'm stumped.

Comment: By definition you need to show that $(\log n)^k\leq M(\log n)$ for sufficiently large $n$. But that looks false. Take $k=2$ for example. The sequence $\frac{(\log n)^2}{\log n}=\log n$ is clearly not bounded.

Comment: This is not true. For every $f(n)$ which goes to infinity, we obviously have $(f(n))^k >> f(n)$ for all $k\ge2$, since their quotient goes to infinity. Maybe you're confusing with the location of the power?

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry! I made a typo, I wrote the title wrongly initially, but the body of the question still remains true! I'm stumped about the case $(\log{n})^k = O(n)$.

Comment: I see your edit now. I think you simply flipped the sides of the inequality. You actually need to show that $(logn)^k \le Mn$ for $n$ large enough.

Comment: Oh yes, many typos today. That's precisely where I'm stuck.

Comment: $\log(x) \in O(x)$ so $k \log(x) \in O(x)$ so  $k \log(\log(x)) \in O(\log(x))$ so $\log(x)^k \in O(x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x>k+1$ we have that $x^k<k!\frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}<k!e^x$.
Take $x=\log n$ and you get that $(\log n)^k=O(n)$. [Note that $k!$ is a constant.]

Comment: The first inequality seem to not hold (?). Take $k = 2$ and $x=4$, and we have $x >  k+1 = 3$, but $x^k = 4^2  = 16$, compared to $\frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!} = \frac{4^{3}}{3!} = \frac{64}{6} < 16$? Let me know if I misinterpreted anything!

Comment: You are so right. Let me repair this.

Comment: Brilliant! I knew there must be an easy fix to this :)Thanks again for your help!

Comment: The original argument should have worked too, but with $x>(k+1)!$ instead of $x>k+1$ :)

Comment: I noticed you correctly criticized [this answer](https://shorturl.at/ajnru), but you didn't downvote it. Getting upvotes, such wrong answerers continue..

Answer (score 2):

We have $x< e^x$. Set $x = \log(n^{1/k})$. We get
$$\log(n^{1/k})<n^{1/k}$$
or, equivalently
$$(\log n)^k < k^k n$$

Comment: Very neat, though looser than reality.  In fact $x \le e^{x-1}$ with equality only when $x=1$ so $(\log n)^k \le \left(\frac ke \right)^k n$ with equality only when $n=e^k$

Comment: @Henry Yes, I know that the inequality is not tight. In fact, I got it by relaxing the tighter inequality $\log x \le k(x^{1/k}-1)$.